# C++ brace initialization of struct with fixed size array member

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, initializer-list

Consider the following struct:

```
struct IPv6Address {
    uint8_t x[16];

    uint8_t& operator[](size_t pos) { return x[pos]; }
    uint8_t* bytes() { return x; }
}

static const IPv6Address WELL_KNOWN_ADDRESS =       //ff02::1
    {0xff, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
     0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};
```

Brace initialization like this works fine. But once I add a constructor brace initialization doesn't work any more. I'd like to have this constructor in addition to brace initialization:

```
IPv6Address(uint8_t bytes[16]) { memcpy(x, bytes, sizeof(x)); }
```

Obviously no constructors are implicitly defined any more once I add my own constructor. But how can I redefine brace initialization in this case or force the compiler to create all default constructors?

Extra Requirement: I can't use the stdlib because I'm programming for an embedded application

Comment: I don't think you can. Have you considered making a free function that constructs the struct for you?

Comment: Another consideration: `using IPv6Address = std::array<uint8_t, 16>;`

Comment: @MaxLanghof Why wouldn't you be able to? Doesn't `IPv6Address(std::initializer_list<uint8_t>)` do what OP wants?

Comment: Instead of `IPv6Address(uint8_t bytes[16])`, use `IPv6Address(uint8_t const bytes[16])`. Ditto for the indexing: it's generally a good idea to support `const`-ness.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't use the stdlib because I'm programming for an embedded application. But since that feature seems to be part of the core language, It should be somehow possible to redefine that behavior ...

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use double braced lists with your existing constructor (when `initialiter_list` is not allowed)

```
static const IPv6Address WELL_KNOWN_ADDRESS =  
{{0xff, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01}};
```

Answer (score 1):

use a constructor with `initializer_list`

The following constructor should do the job **(did not test it)**.

```
IPv6Address(std::initializer_list<uint8_t> c) : x{} {
  assert(c.size() <= std::size(x));
  std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), x);
}
```

Comment: You should add member initializer `: x{}` so that if the list provided is smaller the left over elements will be zero initialized.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the stdlib since I'm programming for an embedded application.

Comment: @J.Hamme In that case, consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366355/how-to-keep-the-implicitly-declared-aggregate-initialization-constructor

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius  Thanks for that link! I now added a static `IPv6Address fromBytes( const uint8_t* bytes )` method instead. That solves my problem, because IPv6Address remains an aggregate .